# How to check the user input in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input

In the following code, I was trying to create a function in a **public** space of class "SOMECLASS" that would take the user input consisting of float values (declared in a **private** space of the same class)  and verify the user input. If the entered value is not a float, then it will display an error message and the user will be given an opportunity to re-enter this value. However, once some garbage is entered, the loop runs from the very beginning, making the user enter all those values again.

P.S: I know that multiple loops can be created to check each value separately and break the loop if the statement is correct but I want to know if there are any easier ways to do this.

Thank's in advance for help.

```
void SOMECLASS::USER_INPUT() {
    bool loopBool = true; // it is used to manage the do/while loop below;

    do { // the loop is going to run for as long as the boolean is true;

        cout << "   Enter the frequency of the cumputer's CPU in GHz: ";
        cin >> float1;

        if (!float1) { // checks if the value entered is valid;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "INVALID INPUT!!!" << endl << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "   Enter the Hard Drive Capacity in TB: ";
            cin >> float2;

            if (!float2) { // checks if the value entered is valid;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "INVALID INPUT" << endl << endl;
            }

            else {
                cout << "   Enter the capacity of your RAM in GB: ";
                cin >> float3;

                if (!float3) { // checks if the value entered is valid;
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    cout << "INVALID INPUT" << endl << endl;
                }
                loopBool = false;
            }
        }
    } while (loopBool);
};
```

OUTPUT:

```
Computer #1/2
 |--> Enter the frequency of the cumputer's CPU in GHz: 2.3
 |--> Enter the Hard Drive Capacity in TB: 4
 |--> Enter the capacity of your RAM in GB: asd
INVALID INPUT

 `--> The final cost is: ...
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Computer #1/2
 |--> Enter the frequency of the cumputer's CPU in GHz: 2.3
 |--> Enter the Hard Drive Capacity in TB: 4
 |--> Enter the capacity of your RAM in GB: asd
 INVALID INPUT
 |--> Enter the capacity of your RAM in GB: 16
 `--> The final cost is: ...
```

Comment: With `if (!float1)` how do you recognize a failed input from a valid `0.0`? You need to check the state of the *stream*.

Answer (score -1):

If it's mandatory for the number to be float(decimals) then can you do:-
Ceil(number)<>floor(number)

If it's an integer value then floor and ceil will be equal.